# How to interpret SPSS p-value for one tailed tests

Tags: p-value, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics

Suppose H0 = Mean 1 - Mean 2 > or = 0 and HA = Mean 1 - Mean 2 < 0.

We do an unpaired t-test in SPSS to get our p-value. The SPSS p-value is 0,534. This P-value is two tailed, so we have to devide by 2 = 0,267.

Alpha is 0,05.

Now, in my course, sometimes we have to substract our SPSS p-value from 1 and then compare this result to alpha. Other times, we have to compare the p-value you get when you just divide the SPSS-value by 2. How do I know what to do when? Does it depend on the sample mean being positive or negative or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a one-tail (one-sided) p-value when you decided, as part of experimental design:

- The difference (or effect) only matters if it goes in one direction.
- If it goes in the other direction, no matter how large, you will conclude that is due to a coincidence of random sampling so is "not statistically significant".

If you haven't preset the prediction of the difference, and that commitment about what you will conclude if the difference goes the other way, then you simply cannot use a one-tail p-value.

Routinely cutting the two-tail p-value is half to report a one-tail p-value is not a responsible way to analyze data.

Answer (score 0):

If you alpha is 0,05 for example it means that if your calculated P is larger than your alpha you don't have enough evidence to reject your null hypothesis. Important, that is not equal to say that your null hypothesis is true.

Comment: I changed my Answer, i didn't mean to use the word data as n. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If p value >0.05, then we can say it is not significant. This means that we fail to reject the null hypothesis. There are different ways to look for p-value, using SPSS or table. I suggest stick to one method so that you are not confused.